# How to get your post noticed?

Tags: discussion

How can someone get his/her question noticed when there are no replies/comments/answers?

I myself have several questions where...

...[there's no reply/comment at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382962/localize-combobox-items-in-vb-net) (but it did got me the Tumbleweed badge, not sure if I am proud about that :-)

...[someone has asked for more information in a comment, I updated the question, but the other user never returns to answer my updated question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636953/html5-choose-formula-for-output-element-based-on-input)

What is the "best practice" to get your post noticed?

Comment: Chat, bounty, bumping (editing/commenting).

Comment: Good tagging, well-written post, relevant updates, and bounty is all else fails.

Comment: Just want to add that when I searched for "getting nocited" in Meta, I did not get any results. But clearly, my question is a duplicate and can be closed.